# Take a List of Strings and double each character in an arraylist

Tags: java

I am trying to double each letter in a list of Strings in an array loop.

For example:
["abc","def"] --> ["aabbcc","ddeeff"]

```
    ArrayList<String> aa;
    aa = new ArrayList<String>();

    String res = "";

    for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++){
        char at = aa.get(i);
        res=res+at+at;
    }
    return res;
```

I am still new to coding and as you can see, my code is a mess. Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please provide an [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you provide code. Currently, when I try to run your code, I am getting 2 errors: `words` is not defined; and `aa.get(i)` gives an `incompatible types` error since `get()` returns a `String`, yet you want a `char`.

Comment: @natn2323 Sorry for not defining. 'words' is the list of Strings where I need to double the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You some problems with your implementation:

- You interact over `words` array but uses the index over the `aa`. As it was never added items to it, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- You issue a `return res` but this will return only one string, not an array of words.

According to your example this can be done this way:

```
public static ArrayList<String> doubleWords(ArrayList<String> input) {
  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String string : input) {
     String word = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        word += ""+string.charAt(i)+string.charAt(i);
     }
     result.add(word);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Your output for an `ArrayList` with `[abc, def]` will be `[aabbcc, ddeeff]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your list of words and then for each word in the list iterate through the characters in the string, like so:

```
public ArrayList<String> doubleWords(ArrayList<String> words) {
    ArrayList<String> doubledWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String word : words) {
        String newWord = "";
        for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
            newWord = newWord + word.substring(i, i+1) + word.substring(i, i+1);
        }
        doubledWords.add(newWord);
    }
    return doubledWords;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 this can also be achieved in the following way:

```
String input = "abc";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
input.chars().forEach(value -> builder.append((char)value).append((char)value));
```

Remeber to convert the `int` value back to a `char` before you append it.

Output for above program:

```
System.out.println(builder.toString());
// aabbcc
```

Comment: If you want to append more than two times i would suggest to loop over `append` rather than appending more times.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //response list
 ArrayList<String> aa; 
aa = new ArrayList<String>();


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
String word;
 // iterate list of words
for(int i=0; i < words.size(); i++){
        //get word 
        word = words.get(i);
         //iterate each character in word
        for(int j =0; j < words; j++) {
        //append each char twice in StringBuilder 
        sb.append(word[j).append(word[j]);
       } 
     //add word to output list 
    aa.add(sb.toString());
     //empty StringBuilder for next word
     sb.setLength(0);
} 

return aa;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done only by java stream api without any temporary variables:

```
List<String> result = listOfWords.stream().
        map(value -> String.valueOf(                          // new result String(doubled word)
            value.chars()                                     // get chars for each original string
                .mapToObj(i-> (char)i)                        // cast each char from int to char type
                .map(c -> String.valueOf(new char[]{c, c}))   // create doubled char string
                .collect(Collectors.joining())))              // concatenate all doubled chars
        .collect(Collectors.toList());                        // collect result to list
```